# Android Emulator - Microsoft Surface 4 - small screen next to main screen - incorrect display

Tags: android, emulation

I am new to Android.

I have a Microsoft Surface 4 laptop, and I cannot get Android Emulator to display properly on it.

[Small Screen next to Main Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjcq4.png)

There is a small screen which appears next to the main screen.  My program output is displayed on this small screen, as opposed to the main screen.

I have found that changing the API Level helps. My laptop cannot seem to handle Android Oreo and needs to use Android Nougat.

Thanks,
Ash